# How can I solve the problem as mentioned below?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, fetch-api

I am new to Django and while I was doing some stuff with Django Framework, I came across some problems
My Python Code [views.py]

```py
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
```

and My JavaScript Code is

```
        const formdata = new FormData()
        formdata.append('itemOne', itemValue)
        formdata.append('itemTwo', itemValue)

        fetch("/create", {
            method: 'POST', 
            credentials: 'same-origin', 
            body: formdata,
            headers:{ 
                // 'Accept': 'application/json', 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken")
            }, 
        }) 
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

when I make a POST request as above from my JavaScript code, I get an empty dictionary.
What might be the problem here?
this is my urls.py files' code

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('create', views.create, name='backend')
]
```

How can I resolve the problem? I tried solutions from different websites and videos and none of them worked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JS, but what if you print `request.data` instead of `request.POST` ?